# how read and write to stylesheet in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stylesheet

I want to let my users edit css files.

so I need to load (Read) one of my stylesheets to a textarea and then save (write) it into same stylesheet,
how i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a file containing plain text. Simply load its contents and then save it back.. Simple `File` methods should be ok, maybe implement some kind of a text highlighter to allow nicer editing.

Comment: thanks I found it a few moments ago.

Comment: make sure the user running your application has read/write (write more specifically) to the directory containing your CSS files

Comment: Further to the comment by @AnthonyShaw - do not give your IIS Account write permissions on a folder containing your app's CSS or other resources - rather create a dedicated sandbox folder for this.